# Какая разница между тегом и селектором?

Tags: html, css

Какая разница между тегом и селектором?

Comment: что ты называешь тегом, а что селектором?

Comment: Тег, это хтмл тег, а селектор, это то, как обратится к нужному тегу(ам).

Comment: Такая же как человек и его имя

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Tag https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CSS_Selector вот определения. Это просто разные сущности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Html**-теги - элементы разметки html-документа.
**CSS**-селекторы - указатели, к какому html-тегу нужно прописать css-правила.

Например:

```css
h1 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<H1> Заголовок</H1>
```

Селелекторы могут указывать не только на html-тег, но и на класс и на id и на некоторые другие элементы разметки.
Например:

```css
.colorgray {
  color: "#ссс";
}

#top {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что если я пропишу в css файле свойства для тега p, например, так: p { color: red; }, то здесь p – это селектор, а если я потом напишу в html файле <p> Текст </p>, то здесь p – это уже тег.

Comment: @ВикторЯрский да

Comment: @ВикторЯрский почти так. Только вначале ты формируешь html и только потом его "разукрашиваешь" с пом css.

Comment: @ВикторЯрский, в контексте web'а не помешает знать еще и про **хэш теги**. они же "якоря" в ссылках. `site.ru/index.html#footer` - здесь `#footer` хэш тег, указывающий на html тег с атрибутом `id='footer'` сам этот атрибут уже якорь(или наоборот, не помню уже...) как то так... при переходе по якорной ссылке, браузер прокручивает страницу до "целевого" элемента с якорем